# Почему не удаляется класс CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Сделал модальное окно, для закрытия добавил svg картинку, при клике которой должно закрываться это окно путем удаления CSS класса modal_active. Но почему то он его не удаляет, или удаляет и вновь создает, в чем проблема?

```js
const openModalWindow = () => {
  const onlineList = document.querySelector(".onlineUser");
  const modalWindow = document.querySelector(".modalWindowList");
  if (!onlineList || !modalWindow)
    return;
  onlineList.addEventListener("click", (e) => { // при клике на надпись Online
    e.preventDefault();
    modalWindow.classList.add("modal_active"); // добавляем класс modal_active
  });
};
openModalWindow();

const closeModalWindow = () => {
  const modalWindow = document.querySelector(".modalWindowList");
  const closeWindow = document.querySelector(".closeButton");

  closeWindow.addEventListener("click", (e) => { // при клике на картинку крестика 
    e.preventDefault();
    modalWindow.classList.remove("modal_active"); // удаляем класс modal_active
  });
};
closeModalWindow();
```

```css
.modalWindowList {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal_active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="onlineUser">&#9776; Online list
  <div class="modalWindowList">
    <div class="modalBody">
      <div class="closeButton">X</div>
      <div class="onlineList"><span class="textOnline">Online</span>
        <div class="usersList"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.closeButton` у вас расположен внутри `.onlineUser`, поэтому когда вы кликаете по кнопке закрытия модального окна, вы незаметно для себя кликаете и по кнопке открытия.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя не объявлен слушатель до тех пор пока не вызовется какая либо из двух функций (openModalWindow или closeModalWindow).

Я предлагаю тебе такую реализацию без функций вовсе:

```
  const onlineList = document.querySelector(".onlineUser");
  const modalWindow = document.querySelector(".modalWindowList");

  let opened = false

  onlineList.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (opened) {
      modalWindow.classList.add("modal_active");
    } else {
      modalWindow.classList.remove("modal_active");
    }
    opened = !opened;
  });
```

И проверь с помощью `console.log(onlineList)` добавился ли ли объектов в константу, если не отработает.
В таком случае тебе нужно будет объявить JS после того как отрисуется HTML, просто напиши JS в самом конце файла.